# Applications for XP, Vista and 7

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-vista

I'm looking at writing an application for my dissertation that runs on XP, Vista and 7. Would you say C# or C++ is the best language? Sorry I'm new to programming and wanted some expert opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Two guidelines:

1. Use C# (or even Visual Basic .NET) if you need something to work (mainly) only on Windows **and** if you don't care if your application takes a little while to start up or ends up being a few nanoseconds slower than its native counterpart. If you're new to programming, you might find Visual Basic .NET to be a lot more like English than C#, and there's no real reason to choose one over the other: they both end up being the same kind of executable with the same power and performance. (Furthermore, debugging is also easier with C#, so try that.)
2. Use a native language (like C or C++) if you need more speed/power, especially if you need to be sure that it's *your* code that's executing, not some translated version of it. If you're new to programming, this **will** be overwhelming (not to mention time-consuming and confusing), so I highly *don't* recommend it.

If you don't mind another option, though, also take a look at Java -- it's similar to C# in some ways but it's designed to be simpler in other ways, and also to be platform-independent.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you want to ask is 'What is the difference between C# and C++?' because there is no clear cut answer for the question of which is better.

As for writing an application to work on those three operating systems, both languages work well. Because you are a beginner in programming, I would use C# just because it is much easier to learn.

Answer (score 1):

C# runs on top of the .NET Framework, which will clean up some of your mistakes especially if your new to programming. It's also easier to produce and output of your application. All that of a cost, C++ is much more faster more complex and requires experience before you can build something useful or high profile looking.